# Transform columns to rows - Pivot not working (ORACLE 11g)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pivot, pivot-table

I'm having trouble to use pivot on a table.

Query:

`SELECT CONCAT(LTRIM(P_NAME), CONCAT(' ', LTRIM(P_LASTNAME)))  AS FULL_NAME
 FROM PERSON
 WHERE PERSON_ID = XX`

Result:

`FULL_NAME
Maria Tasso Tagliari
Lucas O.R. da Silva
Guilherme O. Ribeiro da Silva
Cristina De Oliveira
Inês De Oliveira
Luiz Ribeiro da Silva
Gabriela de Aro Ribeiro da Silva`

I need to return all those names on a single row with a column for each name. The column name doesn't matter (FULL_NAME01, FULL_NAME02 .....)

I'm having problems using pivot because I don't have a column to use an aggregate function.

Could somebody help me with this ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
with x as (
    select 1 as person_id, 'JOE BLOW' as fullname from dual
    union all
    select 1 as person_id, 'JOE SNOW' as fullname from dual
    union all
    select 2 as person_id, 'JANE DOE' as fullname from dual
)
select *
from 
(
 select person_id, fullname, row_number() over (partition by person_id order by fullname) rnum
 from x
)
pivot (
  max(fullname) 
  -- allow up to 5 names per person
  for rnum in (1 name1,2 name2,3 name3,4 name4,5 name5)
);
```

Output:

```
PERSON_ID   NAME1   NAME2   NAME3   NAME4   NAME5
1   JOE BLOW    JOE SNOW            
2   JANE DOE
```

Edit: 
If you want a separate row based on an additional STATUS field, with up to 5 names per person, per status, then you'd have:

```
with x as (
    select 1 as person_id, 'JOE BLOW' as fullname, 'Active' as status from dual
    union all
    select 1 as person_id, 'JOE SNOW' as fullname, 'Inactive' as status from dual
    union all
    select 1 as person_id, 'JOE ROGAN' as fullname, 'Inactive' as status from dual
    union all
    select 2 as person_id, 'JANE DOE' as fullname, 'Active' as status from dual
)
select *
from 
(
 select person_id, fullname, status, row_number() over (partition by person_id, status order by fullname) rnum
 from x
)
pivot (
  max(fullname) 
  -- allow up to 5 names per person
  for rnum in (1 name1,2 name2,3 name3,4 name4,5 name5)
);
```

Output:

```
PERSON_ID   STATUS  NAME1   NAME2   NAME3   NAME4   NAME5
1   Active  JOE BLOW                
1   Inactive    JOE ROGAN   JOE SNOW            
2   Active  JANE DOE
```

So person_id=1 has 1 active name, and 2 inactive names.

Comment: It worked here !!
But if I don't know the number of IDs?
I tryied to use IN (ANY) but it didn't work.
Thx for helping !!

Comment: glad it worked for you.  Not sure what you mean by "if I don't know the number of IDs".  You mean the "person_id"?  That could be a varchar or whatever your system uses.  If you mean how many different names you may find, you'll have to set a hard limit (5 or 10 or whatever) to make that many columns in the pivot (for non-xml pivots anyway)

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate better what I'm trying to do, I changed the example we are using .
I have a table where people are separated by a status category and I need to put them in a single line grouped by status , but in cases of people with the same status only one is selected.
I used the query below for example :

`with x as (
    select 'JOE BLOW' as fullname, '1' as status from dual
    union all
    select 'JOE SNOW' as fullname, '1' as status from dual
    union all
    select 'JANE DOE' as fullname, '2' as status from dual)
select *
from 
(
 select fullname, status
 from x
)
pivot (
  max(fullname) 
  for status in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
);`

Here is the result:

```
1           2           3           4           5           
JOE SNOW    JANE DOE
```

As you can see, there are two records with status '1', but only one was returned.

Another question, can we parameterize the contents of the IN() clause?